# Detecting a html element moving over another html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, setinterval

In my web page i have two square boxes(div tags).The box 'a' starts to animate from left and moves over box 'b' and continues to the end.I want to alert the user when the box 'a' moves over box 'b'.I was able to accomplish this using the co ordinates of both boxes and by using
 setInterval(function(){

//code to check the overlap and alert

},1);
.I wanted to know if there was another simpler way of doing the same?? as i consider
 setInterval(function(){},1); is very costly i.e to call the function evry millisecond.Any solution regarding this would be of great help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval with an interval of 1 ms will work for you! every ms you check to see if box a is within the range of box b, exactly as you suspected

Comment: Ya it works exactly fine..What i wanted to know was if there was any other solution...As i considered using it evry millisecond was costly, if not on web but atleast on mobile it would kill the performance..